# How do I use contains and not contains in a single xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

Consider this element.

```
<a href="#justicefornirmala"></a>
```

I'm using xpath to select it like

```
//a[contains(@href,"nirmala") and not contains(@href,"nepal")]
```

But this is not selecting the `<a>` tag. What am I missing here ? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a syntax error. Doing this fixes it.

```
//a[contains(@href,"nirmala") and not(contains(@href,"nepal"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
//a[contains(@href,"nirmala")][not(contains(@href,"nepal"))]
```